# jquery/html : Validating every button of html form using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a login form that needs to be validated . It has a couple of buttons . I need to validate my form in such a way that if the user forgets values in the button then i flag an error . However on success i move to a new page to continue work . i have the following 
but validation is not happening .

JQ :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#txtEmpid').click(
                    {
                        rules: {
                            txtEmpid: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
                        }
                    });
                    $('#txtPassword').click(
                    {
                        rules: {
                            txtPassword: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
                        }
                    });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML form ( index.html):

```
  <FORM NAME="frmLogin" ACTION="Login.jsp" METHOD="post" >
        <fieldset>
            <div class="text-center">
                <label class="text-center" for="txtEmpid">Employee Id </label>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmpid" name ="txtEmpid" placeholder="Employee Id">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <label class="text-center" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name ="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FIELDSET>
```

The above it not working . I am sure my jquery plugins are correct as i am able to do a validation for the entire submit form by using .validate jquery method .

I want to do validate  every button . If values are ok then i move to new page (Login.jsp) else i stay on index.html and flag the problem . How do i do it ? Whats my mistake ?

Comment: form is not closed....is that typo..?

Comment: no no man ! the form displays just fine :-) just that my buttons are not validated . if i input values correctly it goes to Login.jsp just fine . I think is a problem with basic sytax/rules . So help me out in that regard . I think i am making a dumb mistake .

Comment: well i have added answer have a look

Comment: `rules` and `errorPlacement` are options/methods **only for** the jQuery Validate plugin and must be placed inside `.validate()`... they can't be arbitrarily placed inside of a `.click()` handler or anyplace else outside of `.validate()`.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for pointing it out . Yes i am using the .validate() function and do realise that these cant be placed inside a .click() function . By the way the above is incorrect code . I have accepted the correct answer .

Comment: I know you already accepted the correct answer, but sometimes I simply make comments for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to user `.validate`.

Give form a unique `ID`.

#### **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/PNF2q/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<FORM NAME="frmLogin" ACTION="Login.jsp" METHOD="post" id="FormID">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="text-center">
            <label class="text-center" for="txtEmpid">Employee Id </label>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="text" id="txtEmpid" name ="txtEmpid" placeholder="Employee Id">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <label class="text-center" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name ="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </FIELDSET>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#FormID').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                txtEmpid: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtPassword: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if u r jquery plugin is correct mean this code ll help you...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#formID').validate(
                    {
                        rules: {
                            txtEmpid: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
                        }
                    });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I am sure about my plugins as form validation worked fine . But changing .click() to .validate() also does not work :(  Hmmm

Comment: Got it now ! thaks for ur support !

Answer (score 1):

You applied rules if user clicks only.If user dont clicks on any text box those will not apply.

```
<FORM NAME="frmLogin" ACTION="Login.jsp" METHOD="post" id="formId">
```

and call a function on onsubmit

```
function submitFunction()
{

return  $('#formId').valid();

}
```

or

you can use simply

```
           <input type="text" id="txtEmpid" name ="txtEmpid" class="required" 
           placeholder="Employee Id">

                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="required"  
                name ="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: Ok i realise that problem . so when i change .click to .validate it still doest work :(

Comment: @rockstar if you have any other problem please create a alink